# Vue Dynamic Layouts mounting router-view component twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, layout, vue-component, vue-router

I setup my Vue project to use dynamic layouts - that is, layouts that persist from page to page, assuming the layout for the new page is the same as the last page.  My problem is that when I go to a route with a different layout, the router-link component gets created and destroyed, then created again, which is causing me some issues.  My setup is as follows:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <router-view :layout.sync="layout" />
  </component>
</template>

<script>
import LayoutPortal from '@/layouts/LayoutPortal';
import LayoutOffline from '@/layouts/LayoutOffline';
import LayoutDefault from '@/layouts/LayoutDefault';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    LayoutPortal,
    LayoutOffline,
    LayoutDefault,
  },
...
```

**Some router-view Component**

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import LayoutDefault from '@/layouts/LayoutDefault';

export default {
    ...

    created() {
        this.$emit('update:layout', LayoutDefault);
    },
}
</script>
```

**Layout Default**

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'layout-default',
};
</script>
```

### tldr;

If you setup your project using dynamic layouts, following any of a number of tutorials out there online, when you navigate to a route with a different layout than the last page, the new router-view component gets created, destroyed, then created again.  This causes issues like doubling up on mounted() calls and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately went with nested (child) routes (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html):

```
{
      path: '/portal',
      component: LayoutPortal,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if (!store.getters.auth) {
          next('/login');
          return;
        }

        next();
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: 'home',
          name: 'portal-home',
          component: PortalHome,
        },
        {
          path: 'about',
          name: 'portal-about',
          component: PortalAbout,
        },
        ...
```

In this way I can load up the layout as the parent route, separate beforeEnter logic into separate route groups, and avoid the problem where going to a page with a new layout loads a component twice.

Comment: Not sure I follow how this gets around the issue.  Can you give more specifics on the mechanics of it?

Comment: @AdamYoungers Basically, if you have a parent (layout) component and use child routes, that parent component never gets unmounted unless you go to a route that uses an entirely different parent component.

Comment: @AdamYoungers so in my case, for example, I had a function on a parent component that polled the backend every 10 seconds, but it would double up that call when I switched to a different route in the original layout method.  With the new layout method, it doesn't do that, and continues making the request as normal as you bounce around routes, unless you go to a completely different layout.

Comment: Do you have full example code somewhere? I have a similar setup and mine still load twice.